# How to add pixels in EmguCV

Tags: emgucv

Hi I'm using EmguCV and I enjoy programming with it.

However I'm wondering whether there is an elegant way to add two pixels individually.

To add images, you can use CvInvoke.Add(), but for individual pixel operation, you seems to have to write it in an ugly way,

say you have p, p1 and p2 as EmguCV::Bgr,

you have to write

```
p = new Bgr(p1.b + p2.b, p1.g + p2.g, p1.r + p2.r);
```

I really hate this and tried to write an operator for this. But this is apparently impossible since operator overloading must be in the host class.

Is there any way to do this elegantly?

================Edit================

What I want to do is to calculate the summation of the pixels in an image. So the basic operation in this is to add pixels, or Bgr class.

Comment: Some clarifications on some of your points. If you want elegant code to add two images you can use operator overloading alreadym defined for image class Image<Bgr, Byte> image3 = image1 + image2; as per your request I would simply add an extension method to class image that provide pixel sum functionality? If you care about performance I can suggest you to directly access data pixel array.

Comment: Please look at the update. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have two images `img1` and `img2`:

- If you want to add them you can do `img3` = `img1+ img2`
- If you simply want the summation of each color channel on a single image `img1` you can do:

  `Bgr sums = img1.GetSum();`

  double TotalVal = sums.Blue + sums.Green + sums.Red;

Hope this helps,

Luca

Comment: Though it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Feel free to further explain your question so I can be more specific.

Comment: Please see my new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476050/pixel-wise-summation-and-subtraction-in-emgucv