# Pixel-wise summation and subtraction in EmguCV

Tags: emgucv

I'm looking for an elegant way to perform pixel-wise summation and subtraction in EmguCV.

I'm trying to calculate the Haar-like features of an image.
For a one-dimensional situation, it's done by multiplying the vector [x x x x x x x x] by the following vector element-wise:

```
[ 1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1]
[ 1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1]
[ 1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
```

So I need to add or subtract the element pixels of an image.

Say,

```
Bgr sum = new Bgr();
sum = sum + img[0,0] - img[0,1] + img[0,2] - img[0,3];
```

Obviously this won't compile since there's no operator "+" in class Bgr. I've to make a new Bgr by specifying each of the B, G, R value, which is ugly.

Any idea on performing elegant pixel-wise operation?

[Previous Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435976/how-to-add-pixels-in-emgucv/16440450#16440450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use `img.GetSum()` if you first flip the sign of the pixels you want to be subtracted. You might be able to do that by multiplying the image element-wise with a matrix consisting of `1` and `-1` at the appropriate places.